# Parcel generates import statements to source code and 3rd party library in the bundle

Tags: typescript, bundle, parcel

I'm trying to create a React library and bundle it with Parcel. I use the following settings

```
{
    "source": "src/index.ts",
    "module": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "targets": {
        "module": {
            "includeNodeModules": {}
        },
        "types": {
            "includeNodeModules": {}
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "parcel build"
    },
}
```

In `dist/index.js` everything is bundled correctly - no any external imports, just pure JS code.
But in `dist/index.d.ts` I get 1 import from external library and 2 imports from source code:

```
export const GET_TICKETS: import("@graphql-typed-document-node/core").TypedDocumentNode<
    import("generatedGQLtypes/manage/graphql").ListTicketsQuery,
    import("generatedGQLtypes/manage/graphql").Exact<{
        [key: string]: never;
    }>
>;

//# sourceMappingURL=index.d.ts.map
```

How can I get rid of them and compile them in pure JS code with no dependencies?